# How to forward a request to another match in the router in Nextjs

Tags: next.js

Suppose I have 2 paths in Next.js (page router) that correspond to the current URL - `[...slug].ts` and `something.ts`. So the URL *example.com/something* matches both patterns and ends up in the more accurate of them - in `something.ts`.

This is correct, but in some cases (for example, based on the feature flag) I would want to decide in the `getServerSideProps` method of `something.ts` that I actually want to render `[...slug].ts` to the user (*pass the request to this page*).

Is it possible to somehow tell the router to match another page in Next.js? The only solution I can think of is to unify the server functions of both pages and import the same component, but I'd much rather just **let the request pass to the next match**. Something like:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = ((context) => {
  if (random()) return { bypass: true };
  return { props: { state: "good" } };
})
```

Comment: Have a look at the redirect https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/get-server-side-props#redirect

Comment: @grekier How exactly would you redirect user to the same page (from /something to /something) but with different nextjs module (with [...slug], not something)?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to the slug

```
export const getServerSideProps = ((context) => {
  if (random()) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/something-else', // maybe need something meaningful here
        permanent: false,
      }
    }
  }
  return { props: { state: "good" } };
})
```

This will render the [...slug] assuming you don't have a route called `something-else`

Comment: _ assuming you don't have a route called something-else_ well thats the problem/quesiton; I dont want to use something-else, i need to use something (which I already have and just want to bypass the route matcher).

Comment: And, with the code above, you can use `/something` without any issues and it will show the slug page. The point is, in my example, I send the redirect to `/something-else` which will match `[...slug]` as long as there isn't route that match better.

Comment: Nah, it just gave me endless redirect loop

Comment: Then `/something-else` matches the `/something` path or there is another redirect in slug

Comment: I've tried empty init Next project with 2 blank pages and it just keep redirecting to each other. Do you have some example or link to the docs where is this behavior explained?